# Server Side Timeouts in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I had a developer run a query that had no timeout and it left a transaction open. Around the 8 hour mark tempdb was almost full.

Is there a server side setting for SQL Server to set timeouts to prevent this from happening in the future? Hopefully this setting would override the client timeout.

Comment: Quoting from this somewhat dated article ([There’s no such thing as a query timeout…](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/khen1234/2005/10/20/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-query-timeout/)), that still holds true: `[...]people are often surprised to learn that query timeouts are a client-side concept only`, and `[...]the database engine itself knows nothing of query timeouts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to ask your developer to not do that on a production server. Only allow trustworthy people and/or processes access to your production database. If a process is going to churn through data over a long period of time then make sure there is a basic understanding of sql server logging and in your case, #temp table usage.

[Here](http://www.connectsql.com/2012/09/sql-server-automatically-detect-and.html) is an article on how to kill long running processes on sql server, however, this level of precaution should **never** have to be used IMO.